# onUnbind not being called when binding the activity to a running service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have this activity that starts and binds to a service:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SoundService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
    context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

and I unbind by:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    context.unbindService(serviceConnection);

    super.onStop();
}
```

The service keeps running even after closing the activity.  Look at this scenario:

1. Activity starts the  service and binds to it
2. Activity gets killed, the service keeps running, `onUnbind()` is called
3. Activity starts again, and binds to the running service
4. Activity gets killed, `onUnbind()` is **not** called :(

Why is the `onUnbind()` not being called?

Comment: Could you verify that `onStop()` is being called?

Comment: Why both `startService` and `bindService`?

Comment: return `true` from `onUnbind`

Comment: @pskink this was the solution, please add an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

return `true` from `onUnbind`, next time if you call `bindService` again not only `onRebind` will be called but also when the last clients unbinds also `onUnbind` will be called by the system

Answer (score 1):

How did you start the service ? Please paste that code.

Service will only be stopped after you called `unbindService()` **IF** there are no other clients connected to this service **AND** the service was started with `bind` call with `AUTO_CREATE`. If the service was started with `startService()` then the service will not be stopped until the service calls `stopSelf()` or android terminates it to free memory